# What connotation do these words describing "someone who straightforwardly expresses their" opinion have?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives, connotation

The adjective ones I have heard recently are

- *forward*
- *straightforward*
- *forthcoming*
- *frank*

I was wondering if each of them has positive, negative or neutral meaning?

What are other similar terms that are used for positive, neutral and negative intention?

Comment: Well, you could try *unemployed* for starters.

Comment: @Robusto: What does that belong to? Negative, positive or neutral intention?

Comment: This is a tongue-in-cheek comment. Read *unemployed* literally. Basically saying, "Don't be too outspoken, etc, or you could get fired!"

Comment: @Jimi: I am confused. I thought and still think Robusto meant that a starter can be called unemployed in a straightforward way?

Comment: *for starters* is a common expression that means *to begin with/in the first instance*. Does this make more sense now?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I will expound on the examples you provided and then give a few more of my own.

- ***forward***: Forwardness is not usually considered a positive attribute, as someone who is [too] forward unduly volunteers their opinion or views in a rather annoying manner.
- ***straightforward***: A straightfoward person does and says the right thing, regardless of the consequences. Straightforward fellows are usually considered thoughtful (and simple-minded, perhaps), but not rash and stupid.
- ***forthcoming***: The adjective, *forthcoming* is used to describe persons who willingly provide information. It is not necessarily a positive attribute, and it is sometimes associated with disloyalty.
- ***frank***: A frank person *[calls a spade a spade](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1292717?rskey=Dq01Cm&result=1#m_en_us1292717)*. If especially harsh, such a person could be described as *[brutally frank](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/brutal)*.

Of the four words above, I would say *forthcoming* does not quite belong in the group, as it more concerned with *answers* than *opinions*. Similar adjectives that come to mind are:

- ***[candid](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1230386#m_en_us1230386)***: A candid person speaks the truth in plain terms. This a neutral-positive attribute.
- ***[outspoken](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1274431#m_en_us1274431)***: This is usually a positive attribute. An outspoken person may speak out in defense of the voiceless or the oppressed and against evil. Such a person may also be a *[devil's advocate](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1239921#m_en_us1239921)* or a *[rabble-rouser](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1282606#m_en_us1282606)*. In these cases, *outspokenness* may be regarded as highly undesirable.
- ***[blunt](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1227430#m_en_us1227430)***: A blunt individual speaks the truth *[without fear or favor](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1246476#m_en_us1246476)*. One usually hears the phrase, *[to put it bluntly](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/put_3#put_3__3)*. Someone who is not as blunt may opt to *[put it mildly](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/put_3#put_3__3)*, instead. Indeed, bluntly-expressed thoughts are usually unpleasant, but they tend to be spoken from the mouth of a disciplined, upright or oppressed individual.
- ***[forthright](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1248588#m_en_us1248588)***: Forthrightness is a highly desirable quality. It applies not only to expressed opinions but also to actions and attitudes. A forthright person is honest and straightforward in his or her dealings.
- ***[vituperative](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1304529#m_en_us1304529)***: While a vituperative person may speak the truth, their ultimate goal is to spite or to scorn. This is definitely a negative attribute. There are many other related *v-words*, such as *[venomous](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1303804#m_en_us1303804)*, *[vicious](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1304131#m_en_us1304131)*, *[vindictive](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1303804#m_en_us1303804)*, etc, but these have broader meanings that go beyond the mere expression of opinion.

Comment: I like candid.. that is a great word.

Answer (score 5):

I think you'll find quite an interesting discussion of these and related words in the question  “[Do you agree with these intermediate gradations between ‘frank’ and ‘evasive’?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13405/do-you-agree-with-these-intermediate-gradations-between-frank-and-evasive)” and its answers.

Comment: I should also mention that I don't think it qualifies as a duplicate. More specific answers may be given here.

Answer (score 2):

I also heard people use *upfront*, as a positive attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Another word would be "plainspoken", someone who expresses themselves in ordinary, easy-to-understand language rather than gussying up their elocutions with a plethora of hifalutin sesquipedalia.

(I should add that "plainspoken" is also largely synonymous with "blunt"; if a plainspoken person doesn't like something, he'll tend to say "I don't like it" rather than beating around the bush.)

Answer (score 1):

There are also colloquial phrases describing such a person. The person might be called "a straight-shooter" or someone who "tells it like it is". Both these phrases can be used positively or negatively, depending on context.

Answer (score -1):

[blatant](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=blatant) -

- without any attempt at concealment; completely obvious; "blatant disregard of the law"; "a blatant appeal to vanity"; "a blazing indiscretion"

Comment: But blatant is applied to some behaviour, not someone. You cannot tell of me that I am blatant, for example.