# How to describe someone who "tells the truth" with no respect for others' feelings?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a friend who just keeps "telling the truth", e.g when he thinks the joke you've just told is stupid, he will say so right after you've finished telling it, paying no respect to people's feelings.

How should I describe him ?

Comment: Related: _[What connotation do these words describing “someone who straightforwardly expresses their” opinion have?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/15333/5822)_

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Blunt*.

It is [defined as](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blunt): characterized by directness in manner or speech; without subtlety or evasion; abrupt and often disconcertingly frank in speech

Comment: ["I'm always frank and earnest with women. Uh, in New York I'm Frank, and Chicago I'm Ernest."](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116908/) (Sam Jackson as Mitch Henessey, *The Long Kiss Goodnight*)

Answer (score 4):

Some might say he is ***direct*** or ***tactless*** or ***free with his opinions***

others might say he just "***calls'em like he sees'em***" or that he ***holds nothing back***

Comment: I'll pick blunt , but your second statement was awesome as well , thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Your friend is ***uncouth*** and has ***no tact***.

If this ***insensitive*** disposition seems rooted in immaturity, he might also be described as ***callow***.

Comment: Surely you mean *callous*, not *callow*!

Comment: @tchrist: Actually, I meant _callow_, as in "juvenile; very immature." If a 15-year-old was being tactless, I might chalk it up to his youth and immaturity. (If it was a 35-year-old who should know better, then _callous_ might be the better adjective).

Answer (score 2):

*Mean*, *brutal*, *merciless*, *thoughtless*, and *heartless* all come to mind. There is no virtue in being unkind.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your friend is "frank to a fault."

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to_a_fault) defines "to a fault" as "used to modiy an adjective which describes some desirable or otherwise positive characteristic," etc.